# WebView Windows Store App C# Ajax Not Working

Tags: c#, html, ajax, xaml, webview

Does Ajax not work in a XAML WebView? Whenever I make an Ajax call it always runs the error callback.

Just for your reference here is the test.js code:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://fake_domain_here/api/v1/api_call",  //I use a real domain name...I just removed it here.
        data: {
            id: 1
        },
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        timeout: 30000,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            window.external.notify("HERE 1");
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            window.external.notify("HERE 2"); //always goes here.
        }
    });
});
```

test.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>In here.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

In the XAML file I do this

```
<Page
    x:Class="APPNAMECLASSHERE"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:LSWApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <WebView x:Name="wv" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="748" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1346" Margin="10,10,0,0" ScriptNotify="script_notify" Source="ms-appx-web:///Assets/www/test.html"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

What do you guys suggest I try to see if that fixes the ajax issue?

**UPDATE 1**

So it sounds like a Cross Domain issue. What is the best way to go around that?

I already have this on my server so I thought that should of fixed any cross domain problems...unless it is set wrong?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName NAME    
ServerAlias ALIAS    
DocumentRoot DIR    
ErrorDocument 503 /system/maintenance.html    
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(css|gif|jpg|png)$    
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/system/maintenance.html -f    
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html    
RewriteRule ^.*$  -  [redirect=503,last]    
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in the ajax I had datatype and not dataType. The difference made it worked. That is strange that Android and iOS doesn't care if it is datatype or dataType. But now it works!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your ajax call should be

```
      $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "fake_domain_here/api/v1/api_call",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
               alert(data.d);
            },
            error: function () { alert(arguments[2]); }
        });
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Just to let you know that my code worked on Android and iOS. It just doesn't work on Windows 8.1 WebView XAML.