# Windows Store App WebView Ajax request from local html file

Tags: ajax, webview, cross-domain, windows-8.1, local

I have a question similar to this [WebView Windows Store App C# Ajax Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714285/webview-windows-store-app-c-sharp-ajax-not-working)

I am loading a local html file onto WebView using :

```
webView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(pageUri, localUriResolver_);
```

I am trying to make a ajax call to remote server. I am getting an error with status=0.
I tried with both jquery and plain XmlHttpRequest, results are same. I am not able to get remote file content.

At the same time, I am able to load local file. As all local files are redirected to my "localUriResolver", i am able to resolve the url and provide the content to ajax call.

Coming to remote content, I know this is cross domain request issue.

Is there a way to get around it on Windows 8.1 WebView. Is there some flag to override the cross-domain origin policy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe I am running into the same issue right now.  It would appear as though my ajax request is not completing.

I see that our API is hit on our server but the complete callback of my jQuery ajax request is never triggered.

Currently investigating why, please update this if you've found a work around or solution.